# How do I remove old hockey tape from drop bars

Tags: handlebars, grips

I used hockey tape on the drop bars for my bike and I need to remove it to replace the brake levers. Over time, the tape has become melted/fused together, and I used lots of layers for extra cushioning, and I can't just peel it off. Are there any tips or tricks for removing it that don't require a Delorean to undo my bad decision to use hockey tape in the first place.

Comment: Never had any trouble.  Of course, I leave the stuff on until it's ready to fall off anyway, and it's usually over a layer of regular handlebar tape.

Comment: (And hockey tape really is the best thing for handlebars.  Though it seems like the last stuff I bought was poorer quality than previous -- like everything else, I guess.)

Comment: The original reason for using hockey tape was that this is on a bike I ride a lot in the rain, and I find that regular bar tape has a habit of coming off quite quickly when subjected to rain.  I think it would be much easier to remove if it was over regular tape. I think I'll just stick to regular bar tape from now on.

Comment: I generally start with regular bar tape and then apply the hockey tape when the bar tape begins to slide (which only takes a few weeks).  A new layer is then applied over the old every year or two, after peeling off any bits that have come loose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A razor blade/knife/x-acto knife should cut it. Hockey shops have special knifes for cutting through hockey tape if you want a specialized device. This shouldn't be a problem for non-carbon bars though, if you're careful.

The residue can be removed with rubbing alcohol or soapy water or mineral spirits (again, for carbon, I'm not sure what you'd do).

Comment: Eucalyptus oil or Tea Tree oil can be used to remove tape adhesives.

Comment: I ended up using a knife to cut through the tape. it took many passes to get through all the layers. By the time I got to the second side of the bars, I found the best way was to cut a single line along the entire length. Then use the knife to get under and start peeling the tape. On I had enough to hold onto, I was able to peel it off as one big piece, like skinning a rabbit.

Comment: I think hockey tape on regular tape should work better than just hockey tape.

Comment: Old gum from adhesive tape - spray and soak it in WD40 or GT85 and then rub off with an old cloth.